# How can I get the total length of multiple strings?

Tags: javascript

I have to get or calculate how many characters are in multiple strings. Example:

```
var aText = [
  "There are only 2 types of people in the world:",
  "Girls and boys, any other thing? I don't know."
];
```

There's more than 80 characters in both strings combined. Another note is that the strings may not be fixed as they may increase or decrease. Is there a way I can do this in JavaScript?

I tried using `aText.length` but this only returned how many strings where in the variable. Which in this case is only 2.

Comment: `aText[0].length`  If you have an unknown number of strings, you can write a loop that iterates through each array entry.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: With a `for` loop and a variable or with the `reduce()` method on the array.

Comment: Have you done any basic programming tutorials? Looping is usually covered pretty early, and summing something using a loop is pretty simple once you know the basics of variables, loops, etc.

Comment: Do you want the number of characters in _each_ string, or in _total_?

Comment: Use [`String.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) to get the length of each item and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to compute the sum of the lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. To find length of characters in all strings that are inside array you can use `array.join('').length`

**.join('')** concatenates all the strings in the array together into a single string with no separator between them. After that **.length** property is used to count total number of characters in the resulting string.
Check this example:

```js
const myArray = Array("A", "BB", "CCC")

console.log(myArray.join("").length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) to get the length of each item and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to compute the sum of the lengths:

```js
const aTexts = [
  "There are only 2 types of people in the world:",
  "Girls and boys, any other thing? i don't know."
];

const totalLen = aTexts.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.length, 0);

console.log({ totalLen });
```

Comment: Another solution, but will the text in the console affect the number if I want to use the number for another purpose

Comment: The purpose of the call to `console.log()` is to show you the outcome of the code. It is not part of the calculation and is not needed. The code that counts the characters is the line `const totalLen = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple forEach loop to loop through the array and get the length of each element in the array.

However, you still need to do something with the length. In this case I'm just showing it in the console.

I added a variable that shows the total number of characters in the array.

```js
var aText = Array(

  "There are only 2 types of people in the world:",

  "Girls and boys, any other thing? i don't know.");

let total = 0;

aText.forEach((a) => {
  console.log(a.length)
  total+=a.length;
});

console.log(total + " characters in the array");
```

Comment: Is there a way to sum them up?

Comment: @VictoryOsiobe I updated my answer so it does

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
const array = [
    "some string of unknown length",
    "another string of some text",
    "blah blah blah"
]

const count = (() => {
    let total = 0;
    for (const entry of array) {
        total += entry.length;
    }
    return total;
})();
```

Comment: Finally, someone that also shows a plain `for` loop! But is the IIFE really necessary?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes -- Is it entirely necessary? No, but it's nice and clean, and IMHO it enhances the readability. When I'm reviewing or de-bugging code, I typically can gloss over the IIFE and don't need to think about what the operations inside it are doing. I can see the IIFE and immediately know that it's performing some operations that return a value into a variable. It's similar to preferring function definitions over function expressions. You might disagree, and that's fine. We're all free to choose our own linguistic styles.

Comment: I don't have anything against it in that regard; I was just thinking of simplicity, as the OP seems to be very much a beginner.

Comment: That's a fair point.